# Validate 3 chunks of strings

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I'm really struggling to get this work.

I have a `string mess` which I need to split up in three chunks. I have done this properly but now I'm stuck in how to validate the two first chunks (`i_clob1` and `i_clob2`) of strings with special characters in the end `"<"`, `">"`, `"</"` - because when I cut these three chunks, my stored procedure appends the three strings and it can look bad when it is cut in those characters.

If the first (`i_clob1`) or second (`i_clob2`) chunks contains the characters in the end, I would like to some how expand the string so that I don't have the characters in the end or maybe trim it? without loosing the characters. And the characters will then be in the next string. The last chunk (`i_clob3`) dont need to be validated because it will always have the last bit of text.

I really hope someone have an answer to my riddle :-)

My happy schenario is when it cut the string in some random text instead of those characters.

My current code:

```
public void Enqueue(string queueName, string mess)
        {
            if (mess.Length >= 3 && mess.Length <= 32000 * 3)
            {
                int lastStart = 2 * mess.Length / 3;
                int lastLength = mess.Length - lastStart;

                string i_clob1 = mess.Substring(0, (mess.Length / 3));
                string i_clob2 = mess.Substring(mess.Length / 3, mess.Length / 3);
                string i_clob3 = mess.Substring(lastStart, lastLength);


            OracleCommand cmd = null;
            try
            {
                cmd = new OracleCommand("", m_Connection)
                    {
                        CommandText = m_InSpName,
                        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    };


                //add Aq queue name 
                OracleParameter qName = new OracleParameter("qname", OracleType.VarChar)
                    {
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input,
                        Value = queueName
                    };

                //add message to enqueue
                OracleParameter message1 = new OracleParameter("i_clob1", OracleType.Clob)
                    {
                        Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                    };
                OracleParameter message2 = new OracleParameter("i_clob2", OracleType.Clob)
                {
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                };
                OracleParameter message3 = new OracleParameter("i_clob3", OracleType.Clob)
                {
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
                };

                i_clob1 = i_clob1.Replace("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>", "");
                message1.Value = i_clob1;
                message2.Value = i_clob2;
                message3.Value = i_clob3;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(qName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(message1);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(message2);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(message3);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //rethrow exception and make sure we clean up i.e. execute finally below
                throw new Exception("An error has occurred trying to deliver to the queue", ex);
            }

            finally
            {
                if (cmd != null)
                {
                    cmd.Dispose();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

This is an example of my input. Normally it will be about 30.000 characters total.

```
<item>
    <item_number>1231</item_number>
    <item_title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_title>
    <item_pbl_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_pbl_code>
    <item_dep_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_dep_code>
    <item_off_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_off_code>
    <item_digitized_timestamp>2013-11-04 09:07:56</item_digitized_timestamp>
    <item_source_url>Loremadsa/adad1231/12312</item_source_url>
    <item_cat_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_cat_code>
    <item_ars_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_ars_code>
    <item_ric_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_ric_code>
    <item_rle_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_rle_code>
    <item_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_code>
    <subjects>
        <sub_keyword />
    </subjects>
    <item_description1>A lot of text goes here</item_description1>
    <item_description2>A lot of text goes here</item_description2>
    <item_description3>A lot of text goes here</item_description3>
</item>
```

The description fields would normally be about 10 - 20.000 characters

My output would be with the new solution:

first chunk

```
 <item>
        <item_number>1231</item_number>
        <item_title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_title>
        <item_pbl_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_pbl_code>
        <item_dep_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_dep_code>
        <item_off_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_off_code>
        <item_digitized_timestamp>2013-11-04 09:07:56</item_digitized_timestamp>
        <item_source_url>Loremadsa/adad
```

second chunk

```
1231/12312</item_source_url>
    <item_cat_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_cat_code>
    <item_ars_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_ars_code>
    <item_ric_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_ric_code>
    <item_rle_code>Lorem ipsum dolor sit</item_rle_code>
    <item_code>Lorem ipsum dolor
```

third chunk

```
      sit</item_code>
    <subjects>
        <sub_keyword />
    </subjects>
    <item_description1>A lot of text goes here</item_description1>
    <item_description2>A lot of text goes here</item_description2>
    <item_description3>A lot of text goes here</item_description3>
</item>
```

Comment: It might help if you could post an example of your input and expected output.

Comment: I would choose `XDocument` or some other built-in functionality to parse the xml rather than treating it as text.

Comment: Your explanations, your knowledge, your effort, etc. are not inside what is expected here (more or less inside what a custom software development company expects from their clients: a list of not-well-defined requirements). As you can see, I have posted an answer (even though, didn't like too much when you weren't too communicative in the last question, the one you deleted), because as far as I delivered the previous algorithm... but, please, see this as something COMPLETELY EXCEPTIONAL. I hope that you will use SO as expected in the near future.

Comment: @varocarbas Im sorry to hear that you don't see my question the way you want it to, but I am trying to explain the best I can in this situation. I have tried to solve this issue in a while without a good attempt and no good examples of code from my side. Therefore I haven't had an example to the riddle on the previous post. Anyway I appreciate your answer and your effort.

Comment: You don't have to be sorry. If you think that I am right, just work on this front a bit harder (I always say things to help... you don't have too much experience in SO and thought that you needed a couple of clarifications regarding what most of people think here).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description (and your previous question), I understand that you want to perform the division by accounting for both chunk-size and chunk-contents; both restrictions cannot be brought into account simultaneously and, in any case, you have to set a preference (e.g., if the given chunk contains a character which has to be "moved" to the next chunk, but this next chunk has already the maximum size, what should be done?). I understand that this preference is defined as follows:

- You divide the chunks on account of the size (30000) but by allowing
  always a big enough "redundant bit" (maximum size allowed is 32000).
- The corrections by content (shown in the code below) are performed after the aforementioned division by size; and thus it can safely be assumed that there will be no size limitation (corrections can be applied blindly as far, in the worst scenario, there will always be a 2000 redundant length).

Code performing the corrections as described above:

```
string i_clob1 = "anything1 </";
string i_clob2 = "anything2 </";
string i_clob3 = "anything3 </";

string allTogether = i_clob1 + i_clob2 + i_clob3;
int start2 = i_clob1.Length;
int length2 = i_clob2.Length;
int start3 = start2 + length2;

string[] bitsToAvoid = new string[] { "</", "<", ">"};
string i_clob1_out = i_clob1;
foreach (string bit in bitsToAvoid)
{
    if (i_clob1_out.Substring(i_clob1_out.Length - bit.Length) == bit)
    {
        start2 = start2 - bit.Length;
        length2 = length2 + bit.Length;
        i_clob1_out = allTogether.Substring(0, start2);
        break; //Just one wrong bit is assumed to be present
    }
}
string i_clob2_out = allTogether.Substring(start2, length2);
foreach (string bit in bitsToAvoid)
{
    if (i_clob2_out.Substring(i_clob2_out.Length - bit.Length) == bit)
    {
        start3 = start3 - bit.Length;
        i_clob2_out = allTogether.Substring(start2, start3 - start2);
        break; //Just one wrong bit is assumed to be present
    }
}
string i_clob3_out = allTogether.Substring(start3);


i_clob1 = i_clob1_out; //"anything1 "
i_clob2 = i_clob2_out; //"</anything2" 
i_clob3 = i_clob3_out; //"</anything3 </"
```

NOTE: This answer is relatively adaptable (`bitsToAvoid` can be updated with as many elements as required), although within certain limits: it was created after having read the original description of the problem, where a shortlisted amount of characters were referred. In case of intending to define the "bits to avoid" in a more complex way (e.g., making sure that the given closing-node-tag is present or not), this algorithm should be taken as a mere starting point and would have to be appreciably improved (most likely, by accounting for some XML analysis).